# How to save entity and avoid creating of new model, using EF?

Tags: c#, json, xml, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a model:

```
public class PersonModel
{
    [Key]
    [JsonProperty("ix")]
    [XmlElement("ix")]
    public int Index { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("content")]
    public ContentModel Content { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "content")]
public class ContentModel
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("visits")]
    [XmlElement("visits", IsNullable = true)]
    public int? Visits { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeVisits() { return Visits != null; }
    [JsonProperty("date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("date")]
    public string dateRequested
    {
        get { return Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); }
        set { Date = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); }
    }
}
```

And he is like that, bacause I want to have `xml` tree that looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PersonXmlModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ix>5</ix>
  <content>
    <name>Jadon</name>
    <date>2009-12-21</date>
  </content>
</PersonXmlModel>
```

But also I want to save the object to the database when using `EF`:

```
public void AddItem(PersonModel request)
{
    PersonModel dataItem = new PersonModel
    {
        Index = request.Index,
        Content = new ContentModel
        {
            Name = request.Content.Name,
            Visits = request.Content.Visits,
            Date = request.Content.Date
        }
    };
    _context.Requests.Add(dataItem);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

And database table has columns:

```
Index
Name
Visits
Date
```

[image: table columns]

And I was wondering, is there any way to mark my model's properties with some `EF` attributes to save the object directly to DB and avoid using some additional model like this?

```
public class PersonModelDatabase
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Visits { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Below is a solution that fixes problem, but is against DRY.

```
[Table("Requests")]
    public class PersonModel
    {
        [Key]
        [JsonProperty("ix")]
        [XmlElement("ix")]
        [Column("Index")]
        public int Index { get; set; }
        [Column("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Column("Visits")]
        public int? Visits { get; set; }
        [Column("Date")]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("content")]
        public ContentModel Content { get; set; }
    }

    [ComplexType]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "content")]
    public class ContentModel
    {
        [Key]
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        [XmlElement("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("visits")]
        [XmlElement("visits", IsNullable = true)]
        public int? Visits { get; set; }
        public bool ShouldSerializeVisits() { return Visits != null; }
        [JsonProperty("date")]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("date")]
        public string dateRequested
        {
            get { return Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); }
            set { Date = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A database has tables and in your case the table is ContentModel.  PersonModelDatabase class should have a property ContentModel not Index, Name, Visits, and Date.

Comment: Yes, you can use mark `ContentModel` as [Complex Type](https://entityframework.net/complex-type)

Comment: @jdweng I would like to use `PersonModel` to add items to the table like in my question (I updated the question with a pictue presenting it)

Comment: @GertArnold EF Core 2.2.x

Comment: @MatJ didnt work

Comment: I updated my question with solution that kind of fixes the problem, but is against DRY, where I am repeating properties from `ContentModel` in `PersonModel` and it does not look pretty

Comment: You should have tagged it asp.net core then. There are difference between both. Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50707606/219933). I've limited experience with core EF

Comment: @MatJ Ok, you was right. And when I tryed before, I missed that `dateRequested` should be `[NotMapped]` for the model creation. Thank you! Previously it was throwing me an exception regarding this property, that is not used for adding new entity.

Comment: @Przemyslaw.Pszemek, No problem mate, I'll flag your question as duplicate of that linked question so that other people can find the answers there. You might get a suggestion above the question regarding the same, You may accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basing on **Mat J** comments and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50707606/8532173) I used second approach from the answer. Besides this I had this I had to mark `dateRequested` with `[NotMapped]` attribute. Otherwise EF was throwing me an exception that

> Invalid column name 'ContentModel_dateRequested'.

Working solution:

```
public class PersonModel
    {
        [Key]
        [JsonProperty("ix")]
        [XmlElement("ix")]
        public int Index { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("content")]
        public ContentModel ContentModel { get; set; }
    }

    [ComplexType]//added
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "content")]
    public class ContentModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        [XmlElement("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("visits")]
        [XmlElement("visits", IsNullable = true)]
        public int? Visits { get; set; }
        public bool ShouldSerializeVisits() { return Visits != null; }
        [JsonProperty("date")]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]//added
        [XmlElement("date")]
        public string dateRequested
        {
            get { return Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); }
            set { Date = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); }
        }
    }
```

And added new method in my `ApplicationDbContext` class:

```
//added
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<PersonModel>(table =>
        {
            table.OwnsOne(
                x => x.ContentModel,
                content =>
                {
                    content.Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
                    content.Property(x => x.Visits).HasColumnName("Visits");
                    content.Property(x => x.Date).HasColumnName("Date");
                });
        });
    }
```